# Llenado de matrices en java script

Tags: javascript, array, matrices

si tengo que llenar una matriz de la siguiente forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el siguiente codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de que manera lo podria realizar

Comment: Muestra el código _como texto, con formato_. Además, ¿cuál es realmente la pregunta?

Comment: Sería bueno que siguieras las recomendaciones, por lo menos de poner lo que expresas en la imágen como texto, el ejercicio está entretenido y la opción mas sencilla es la opción 1, yo realicé el ejercicio y bueno, lo hice en ambas opciones pero no lo compartiré así.

Answer (score 1):

Esta seria mi solucion

El codigo trara si la variable i es un numero par la matriz se empieza a llenar desde el principio de la fila, y si i es un numero impar la matriz se empieza a llenar desde el final de la fila.

```js
    var n = prompt("Digite el tamaño de la matriz")

    var matriz = []
    var con = 1

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var array = new Array()
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                array[j] = con;
                con++;
            }
        } else {
            for (var j = n-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                array[j] = con;
                con++;
            }
        }
        matriz.push(array)
    }

    console.log(matriz);
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero en lo sucesivo evita responder a preguntas mal formuladas, ya que tienden a terminar cerradas y tu esfuerzo se pierde. Te sugiero leer [answer]. Saludos